# How to post json data with extJS in different browser

Tags: java, json, post, extjs, cross-browser

```
     Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: 'foo.php',    // where you wanna post
          success: passFn,   // function called on success
          failure: failFn,
          jsonData: { foo: 'bar' }  // your json data
      });
```

the key am getting this data in server side by

```
    StringBuffer myjson = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
          BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
         myjson.append(line);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

but in case of firefox use @ server side myjson is empty. google chrome works like a charm.

I need to send the other params also so am appending that in url as of now.

instead of "jsonData" in client side if am using params i have to specify some key then i can take it server side. but need to use firefox. chrome is encoding the data.

pls help me guys and thanks as well

note: only post method is needed

with chrome:

[image]

with firefox :

[image]

Comment: That's cross-domain, not cross-browser.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what the problem is. Sounds like you are getting different results in Chrome vs Firefox, right? Have you tried clearing your cache? You haven't specified a "method" for the request, so I think it may be GET instead of POST by default. And sometimes there are caching issues involving javascript.

Comment: what is in  the responseText?

Comment: added the request image of both firefox and chrome. note:image edited for undisclosed matters

Comment: The post from firefox generates a 500 internal error. Look in the server log files, and make sure your code doesn't ignore any exception like it does in your snippet. Use a debugger to understand what happens at server-side.

Comment: in firefox the jsondata is going with parameter key "some blah" (i.e json data) and the request data is empty in server side.in chrome it is going without any parameter key and the request data is correct as exactly in server side.

Comment: 500 error is because of session out while am taking the screenshot